# Moving Large Files Between Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, copy

I NEVER have to do this. But I know its a common problem. Yet, I'm not sure how to tackle it. I have a server (Windows Server 2008) that I access remotely. This server is NOT on the same domain as my local machine. I need to copy a 700MB file from my remote server down to my local machine.

What is the best and quickest way to do this? I've tried the \[ipAddress]\c$ however, Windows Explorer fails to connect. It says "Windows Cannot Access [ipAddress]".

Thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach should work, however you need a double backslash: `\\[ipAddress]\c$`

Furthermore make sure that the Windows Firewall and any third party firewall is disabled or allows these connections

Comment: How do I "allow" this type of connection? What is this "type" of connection called? Thank you so much!

Comment: The Protocols you need to enable are `CIFS` and `SMB`. You can allow these in your firewall if you are using any

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the computer on your domain can reach the server that is not?

Have you tried pinging it first and making sure you can get there?

Also make sure that printer and file sharing is enabled, I would give you more details but I am not sure what OS your using.

Comment: If his Firewall is on then ping might not reply either.